# Numpy - set first max value over multiple axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, max

I have a multidimensional array with the last two dimensions corresponding a "window". For each "window" in the array my goal is to set the first max value in the window to 1 and the rest of the values to 0. For example, for one window, we have this assignment:

```py
[[0., 0., 0.],          [[0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1.],    ->     [0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 1., 1.]],          [0., 0., 0.]]
```

Now, i want to do this for all windows, where each window is on the last two dimensions, i.e. `axis=(-1,-2)`. This is what I have tried so far:

```
# windows
x = np.array([[[[[[0., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 1., 1.],
                  [0., 1., 1.]],

                 [[0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 0.]]],

  
                [[[0., 1., 1.],
                  [0., 1., 1.],
                  [0., 1., 1.]],

                 [[1., 1., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 0.]]],


                [[[0., 1., 1.],
                  [0., 1., 1.],
                  [0., 1., 0.]],

                 [[1., 1., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 0.],
                  [1., 0., 1.]]]]]])

max_indices = np.argwhere(x == x.max()) # all indicies of max values in x
mask = np.zeros_like(x) # start of with everything set to 0

# I can set the first window by doing the following
mask[tuple(max_indices[0])] = 1.0
```

How can i do the same for all other windows? Preferably without looping.

My idea was to find unique values in `max_indices` where the last two dimensions are not taken into account, but i am not sure how to go about this.

**EDIT**

I have a case where `x` in the scenario above is taken from another
array using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, which means that the strides will differ.
Here is the case:

```py
# The image or whatever i want to modify
x = np.array([[[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0.],
                [0., 1., 1., 0.],
                [0., 1., 0., 1.]]]])

# the windows of that image
x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3), strides=(160, 160, 32, 8, 32, 8))
```

Using the solution given by Felipe:

```
y = x[0][0]  # Just unnesting it a bit
yr = y.reshape(-1, 9)
idx = yr.argmax(1)
y0 = np.zeros_like(yr)
np.put_along_axis(y0, idx[:, None], 1, axis=1)
y = y0.reshape(y.shape)

# plug it back
x[0][0] = y

x

array([[[[[[0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0.]],

          [[0., 0., 0.],
           [1., 0., 0.],
           [1., 0., 0.]]],


         [[[0., 1., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0.]],

          [[1., 0., 0.],
           [1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0.]]],


         [[[0., 1., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0.]],

          [[1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0.]]]]]])
```

The shape is the same but with different strides in `x` and `y` it seems as if "plugging it back" causes x and y to not be identical, which I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `np.put_along_axis` (though this is really just a somewhat faster loop).

```
y = x[0][0]  # Just unnesting it a bit
yr = y.reshape(-1, 9)
idx = yr.argmax(1)
y0 = np.zeros_like(yr)
np.put_along_axis(y0, idx[:, None], 1, axis=1)
y = y0.reshape(y.shape)
```

Output:

```
array([[[[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 1., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[1., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]]]])
```

**EDIT**

Not the brightest idea but what I meant is you could reassign it first to a copy of it and then get your strided view again, something like:

```
x0 = x.copy()  # Get a normal view

# [ Run the previous snippet ]

x0[0][0] = y  # Assign the modified version

# Then if you really want another strided view you can recreate it
x0 = x0.reshape(saved_x.shape)  # Reshape it to the original version pre-stride
x = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x0, shape=(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3), strides=(160, 160, 32, 8, 32, 8))
```

Comment: Added a minor edit. The reshaping part was messed up.

Comment: Good idea, reshaping back and forth seems to be the convenient way of doing it.  Although, in my case ```x.strides = (160, 160, 32, 8, 32, 8)```, which is not preserved when doing this. ```x``` in my case comes from another array using ```np.lib.stride_trick.as_strided``` and is not the same strides as the one i gave in the example, ie. ```(432, 432, 144, 72, 24, 8)```.

Comment: I think the reshaping of the array can cause the strides to change, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think as long as you "plug it back" reshaped you are fine, i.e. `x[0][0] = y`. Can't you test it somehow?

Comment: For some reason this does not work. I will edit the post with the exact data i am working with.

Comment: I have updated the post. As you can see, the resulting x is not the same as the output you gave.

Comment: It seems like assigning each window individually does the trick:
```x[0,0,0,0] = y[0,0]```, ```x[0,0,0,1] = y[0,1]``` and so on.
But i am sure there is a better solution.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the stride to reassign the original ```x```, do you mean by looping somehow? As a side note: the size before and and after getting the as_strided view is not the same because the windows are overlapping.
If you could give another solution using this method that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added an edit with my suggestion. Not sure I can help you if that one doesn't do it.